# Trouble translating SQL query to LINQ with join and having count

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, linq

I have this SQL query that I need to translate to LINQ.

```sql
SELECT p.productId, p.name, COUNT(np.ID) AS 'salesLast70', p.quantity
FROM Products p
LEFT JOIN NOrderProducts np
ON np.product_id = p.productId
WHERE np.date_picked > DATEADD(DAY, -70, getdate())
GROUP BY p.productId, p.name, p.quantity
HAVING COUNT(np.ID) < p.quantity
```

Right now I have the following LINQ query.

```cs
var date70 = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-70).Date;
var almostOutOfStockProducts = from p in db.Products
    join np in db.NOrderProducts on p.productId equals np.product_id
    where np.date_picked > date70
    group np by np.ID into npGrp
    where npGrp.Count() < p.quantity
    select p;
```

But `p` cannot be resolved at the end of the LINQ query at `> p.quantity` and `select p`.

I'm sure I am missing something in my LINQ query but I cannot seem to find exactly how to fix it.

### EDIT:

I ended up using `db.Database.SqlQuery();` with the raw query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve what you want you have to lift the quantity, name from the product up into the group by.  You are doing this in your sql version with the clause `GROUP BY p.productId, p.name, p.quantity` but you are not doing this in your linq version.

An example would be to do:

```
var almostOutOfStockProducts = db.Products.Join(db.NOrderProducts, p => p.productId, np => np.product_id, (p, np) => new { p, np })
                            .Where(x => x.np.date_picked > date70)
                            .GroupBy(x => new { Quantity = x.p.quantity, Name = x.p.name, ProductId = x.p.productId})
                            .Where(x => x.Count() < x.Key.Quantity)
                            .Select(x => new {ProductId = x.Key.ProductId, Quantity = x.Key.Quantity, Name = x.Key.Name});
```

In the `GroupBy` I am bringing through the product id, quantity and name from the product into an anonymous type.  This then becomes the key so I can use it in the `Where` clause and also in the `Select` at the end.

Comment: Although this did solve the problem I was facing, I ended up using `db.Database.SqlQuery();` for other reasons.